# get Google AdWords API all campaign stats for total impressions and clicks

Tags: php, google-ads-api

How to get total impressions and clicks for all campaigns on Google AdWords API?
Right now I am doing this way

```
  // Get the service, which loads the required classes.
  $campaignService = $user->GetService('CampaignService', ADWORDS_VERSION);

  // Create selector.
  $selector = new Selector();
  $selector->fields =
      array('Id', 'Name', 'Impressions', 'Clicks', 'Cost', 'Ctr');
  $selector->predicates[] =
      new Predicate('Impressions', 'GREATER_THAN', array(0));

  // Set date range to request stats for.
  $dateRange = new DateRange();
  $dateRange->min = date('Ym01', time());
  $dateRange->max = date('Ymd', time());
  $selector->dateRange = $dateRange;

  // Make the get request.
  $page = $campaignService->get($selector);

  // get results.
  $impressions = 0;
  $clicks = 0;
  if (isset($page->entries)) {
    foreach ($page->entries as $campaign) {
        $impressions += $campaign->campaignStats->impressions;
        $clicks += $campaign->campaignStats->clicks;
    }
  } else {
    //print "No matching campaigns were found.\n";
  }

  return array('impressions'=>$impressions, 'clicks'=>$clicks);
```

I am wondering if I can just get total without using foreach and loop through the  campaigns.

Comment: How were you even able to select Clicks and Cost fields using `CampaignService`? I really need these fields, but they are only available to me through the reports module, which returns data as `.csv`.

Answer (score 1):

To get account-level stats, you can use the AdWords API's `ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT`.  You can download this report in CSV format.

I am a Rubyist, but I believe that this should work for the [PHP client library](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/tree/master/examples):

```
    // AdWordsUser credentials come from "../auth.ini"
    $user = new AdWordsUser();
    $filePath = YOUR_FILE_PATH;
    $user->LoadService('ReportDefinitionService', ADWORDS_VERSION);

    $selector = new Selector();
    $selector->fields = array('AccountId', 'AccountDescriptiveName', 'Impressions', 'Clicks', 'Cost', 'Ctr');

    // no predicate necessary - this report already excludes zero-impression lines; 
    // plus, there is only one line, because it's the whole account

    $reportDefinition = new ReportDefinition();
    $reportDefinition->selector = $selector;
    $reportDefinition->reportName = WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_IT_TO_BE_NAMED;
    $reportDefinition->dateRangeType = 'LAST_7_DAYS';
    $reportDefinition->reportType = 'ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT';
    $reportDefinition->downloadFormat = 'CSV';

    $options = array('returnMoneyInMicros' => TRUE);

    ReportUtils::DownloadReport($reportDefinition, $filePath, $user, $options);
```

Comment: Don't you have to set your customer client id somewhere for this?

Comment: Yep!  The client_customer_id is configured as part of $user.  See this page for an example on setting up your $user: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/Auth/CreateAdWordsUserWithoutIniFile.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$startDate = date('Ymd', strtotime('2018-10-12'));
$endDate = date('Ymd', strtotime('2018-11-13'));
$query = (new ReportQueryBuilder())
    ->select([
        'CampaignId',
        'AdGroupId',        
        'Impressions',
        'Clicks',
        'Cost'
    ])
    ->from(ReportDefinitionReportType::CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT)
    ->where('Status')->in(['ENABLED', 'PAUSED'])
    ->during($startDate, $endDate)
    ->build();
```

Comment: PHP AdWords API v201809 - Set CUSTOM_DATE using ReportQueryBuilder?